# Select latest record for each name

Tags: mysql

I will be making update system and I want to get files to update from database.

Request should give me all files but if there are several rows with the same filename, I want only this with highest value of "version" (number)

So filename in the response will be unique.

(Really sorry that I don't know how to say it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file_version is just for presentation purposes and holds no relational value you can do:

```
select filename, max(file_version) as file_version
  from your_table
 group by filename;
```

Otherwise if file_version must be from the same row as filename then you can do:

```
select distinct a.filename, a.file_version
  from your_table a
  join (select filename, max(file_version) as file_version
          from yourtable
         group by filename) b
    on b.filename = a.filename
   and b.file_version = a.file_version
 order by a.filename;
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check it

Comment: Sure, use `min(file_version)` instead of `max(file_version)`.

Comment: First is working, but I wonder what do you mean by "holds no relational value"

Comment: What I meant was if it was important to select the actual row where the max value exists or did you only need to know the max value?  If selecting the actual row is important you should go with the second query.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` will have perfomance impact, if table is big. It's better to use `LIMIT 1` if you need only one row

```
SELECT 
   file,
   file_version 
FROM 
   file_history
WHERE 
   file = 'filename' 
AND file_version < 5
ORDER BY file_version DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

And you should add an index to `file_version` column, to make this query optimal.

Comment: I want to get newest versions of all files (with minimum and maximum version specified)